# CSS Navigation bar changes size

Tags: html, css

So I want my navigation bar to be the same size as the content box. However when on a different display the navigation size alters and gets distorted. I tried everything to make it stay the same size and I can't

Html Coding -

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(229, 178, 146);
}

ul.navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 80%;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 103.8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
}

.active {
  background-color: #000;
}

div.content {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: -22;
}

div.footer {
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0%;
  margin auto;
}

hr {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #FFF
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTPYE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Shahed's Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <hr/>
  <h1>Shahed Miah's Portfolio</h1>
  <hr/>
  <center>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="content">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
        a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </center><br/>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Copyright &copy;Shahed Miah</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use bootstrap container

Comment: he's/she's not using bootstrap...

Answer (score 1):

change css

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(229, 178, 146);
}
ul.navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 80%;


}
li{float: left;
    width: 25%;}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-decoration: none;

}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
.active {
    background-color: #000;
}
div.content {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: -22px;

}
div.footer {
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    border: solid;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0%;
    margin auto;
}
hr {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #FFF
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: grey;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LLk9a8fq/

Comment: grrr.. faster :P